# Text box to hex to byte

Tags: c#, hex, arrays

hi I have some text boxes  which user enters information such as first name,last name ,... .
I need to convert text boxes' text to hex and then convert the hex to bytes and send to device via rs232.

I know the sending via rs232 part. My question is can I only use `textbox.text.ToString("X")` and after that use the following function to convert hex to byte array?

```
 public static byte[] StringToByteArray(String hex)
{
  int NumberChars = hex.Length;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[NumberChars / 2];
  for (int i = 0; i < NumberChars; i += 2)
  bytes[i / 2] = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(i, 2), 16);
  return bytes;
 }
```

Comment: Edit your question to include this:  *Given ____, I expect ____*.

Comment: I read this article but I can't figure out how to use them to convert string to hex . this is what I wanna do : if the name is "John" for example I want to send "6A6F686E".

Comment: 6A is for a lowercase j by the way, J as in "John" is 4A

Comment: yes you're right.my mistake.

Comment: so how do I solve my problem?

Comment: Don't convert to hex, there is no point.  Use Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox1.Text).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming ASCII (based on your comment):

```
var bytes = textbox.Text
                   .Select(c => (byte)c)  // cast every character to a byte
                   .ToArray();
```

There is no need to convert to hex when you think of `chars` as a set of bits.

To take "john" to "6A6F686E" to bytes (still find it strange to double the data getting sent...):

```
var bytes = textbox.Text
                   .Select(c => (byte)c)   // to byte
                   .SelectMany(b => b.ToString("X"))  // to hex
                   .Select(c => (byte)c) // to "hex-byte"
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: OK. In this way I assume I don't need to declare `byte [] ba = new byte()` and the `var bytes` takes all characters in spite of the length of `textbox.text` ?

Comment: @user2628363:  No other declarations are needed and this will create an array representing all the characters in the text box.  If you need fewer characters, include a `.Take(numberOfChars)` prior to calling `.ToArray()`.

Comment: Thanks It works but the byte values are decimal I want them to be hex.I mean for 'h' it gives me 104 but I want 68

Comment: @user2628363:  So you need to send the byte representation of the hex values of the characters of a string?  Or, do you need to send the byte representation of the string?

Comment: The device I'm developing software for assumes I'm sending the information as hex. but since it's a device I need to put the hex values in a byte array and send to device. so as said before if the name is "john" I should send "6A6F686E" to device but as byte array

Comment: I understand why you think it's strange but my device looks at each byte as one hex number. Because of this I should send each hex representation of char in one hex in one byte. I mean '6A' in above should be sent in one byte. your code sends '6' in one byte and 'A' in another

Comment: when I debug I see 106 in one byte which is decimal for"6A". Are they the same for the device?